# Titanium CLI alloy execution location

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-cli

I recently wrote a small hack to enable writing Titanium apps with TypeScript (https://github.com/developer82/Ti.TypeScript). This involves editing the SDK alloy compiler script.

As you can tell from what I've written the script is located at `/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.appcelerator/install/SDK_VERSION/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/index.js`

When I run my project from Titanium Studio it works great. However when I try to run from command line using `ti build -p ios` I'm getting an error `This project requires the TypeScript hack in Titnaium SDK` - which is a validation I wrote that the hack was applied to the compiler.

The reason for this is that running from command line, the CLI is looking for alloy in `/usr/local/bin/alloy` - I learned that from the following output:

```
[INFO]  Executing Alloy compile: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/alloy compile /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MY_PROJECT/app --config platform=ios,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=universal,deploytype=development,target=simulator
```

Why the different location? Why the CLI doesn't work like Appcelerator Studio? how can I make it work like Appc Studio?

Comment: I believe you've found a workaround as I saw your Medium post. What was it?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator to this problem? no. not yet. Since App Studio doesn't support TypeScript I wanted to work with Atom. And I wanted to run my app (with LiveView) from terminal - and that's the error I got - it tries to run Alloy compiler from wrong location. For now what I'm doing is running the app from AppStudion and writing code in Atom - not idle.

Comment: Ah, yes.. LiveView will always use the Alloy version bundled with the Appcelerator CLI. You'd have to hack into the LiveView plugin (found in the Package Contents of Appcelerator Studio) to change that.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator It happens even if I don't run LiveView. Is this the same Alloy as deployed with SDK (can I just work with it)? or do you recommend finding a hack to force it to work with one in SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution turned up to simpler than I thought... instead of using `ti` command I started using `appc` command:

```
appc run --platform iphone --liveview
```

I think `ti` is the open source version (which uses the alloy installed from node) and `appc` is the Appcelerator platform (that's what Appcelerator Studio runs).

Comment: Correct, `appc run` uses an embedded version of `ti` and `alloy`.